# Spring MVC request mapping based on url parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Requirement is to write a controller to handle POST requests from the below urls:

```
http://hostname:port/com/prod1?id=2&action=add
http://hostname:port/com/prod1?id=2&action=minus

http://hostname:port/com/prod2?id=2&action=add
http://hostname:port/com/prod2?id=2&action=minus
```

Can I have two methods, one for mapping urls with action=add, and another for urls with action=minus? All the requests are POST.

Answer (score 6):

A couple years between question and answer, but **yes** it is possible to route based on query parameters with Spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/com/{product}", params = "add")
String add(@PathVariable("product") String product) {
    System.out.println("add method; product=" + product);
    return "add";
}

@RequestMapping(path = "/com/{product}", params = "minus")
String minus(@PathVariable("product") String product) {
    System.out.println("minus method; product=" + product);
    return "minus";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`No` to my knowledge. According to your url end points,

they are,

1. /com/prod1
2. /com/prod2

For these you can have 2 controller methods for each of these.

EDIT:

If I understand you correctly,

Instead of having the above end points, write 2 controller methods for request mappings,

1. com/add
2. com/minus

If you want to have it in a more granular manner, then

1. com/prod1/add
2. com/prod1/minus
3. com/prod2/add
4. com/prod2/minus

write request mapping methods for the above.

Then you have,

http://hostname:port/com/prod1/add?id=2
http://hostname:port/com/prod1/minus?id=2

http://hostname:port/com/prod2/add?id=2
http://hostname:port/com/prod2/munus?id=2

Or you can use another approach. which is, Just use the generic end points and depending on your request parameters, redirect to different request mappings such as,

1. com/add
2. com/minus

Comment: I want it based on the action (action=add or action=minus), not based on prod1 or prod2.

Comment: @PraveeshP let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two `@RequestMapping` methods to map to two URLs differing only by query parameters. The `@RequestMapping` only binds to the path portion of the URL.

You can have two methods if you dispatch on the `action` value, calling one method for `add` and another for `minus`.

Or, you can make `add` or `minus` a part of the URL path.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible with the following code:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/com/{product}", params = "action=add")
public String add(@PathVariable("product") String product) {
    System.out.println("add method; product=" + product);
    return "add";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/com/{product}", params = "action=minus")
public String minus(@PathVariable("product") String product) {
    System.out.println("minus method; product=" + product);
    return "minus";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).